# Determining nested or crossed random effects in study design

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-models

I've found several versions of the canonical example of nested random effects about classes in schools or students in classes.. However, I'm still having a hard time connecting the school/classes/pupils examples to my current repeated measures study design.

I have 20 people from the community all running in 3 different shoes (A, B, C), each at 2 different set speeds (low F and high) while I measure their HR. Every subject will complete 6 trials.

I know that I have speed and shoe type as fixed effects, and that I need include subject as a random effect in my lme model, but I'm not sure how to include shoe and speed as random effects. Are they nested because although every subject runs in shoe A, B, and C across the same speeds, the outcome measurements (HR) are different for each subject?  If that's the case, can someone explain what a crossed random effect might look like in this situation?